ABI Error, while interacting with a smart contract deployed in a private permissioned besu blockchain network
I got the following error while interacting with a smart contract deployed in a permissioned Besu network:
AbiError: Parameter decoding error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at decodeParametersWith (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/esm/api/parameters_api.js:97:15)
    at decodeParameters (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/esm/api/parameters_api.js:206:49)
    at decodeFunctionReturn (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/esm/api/functions_api.js:250:20)
    at ContractBuilder.<anonymous> (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/esm/contract.js:779:24)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/esm/contract.js:20:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
  cause: undefined,
  code: 205,
  props: {
    internalErr: AbiError: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
        at decodeParametersWith (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/esm/api/parameters_api.js:88:19)
        at decodeParameters (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/esm/api/parameters_api.js:206:49)
        at decodeFunctionReturn (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/esm/api/functions_api.js:250:20)
        at ContractBuilder.<anonymous> (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/esm/contract.js:779:24)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (file:///Users/ani/Desktop/deployed/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/esm/contract.js:20:58)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
      cause: undefined,
      code: 205,
      props: {}
    }
  }
}

Node.js v22.9.0


P.S. It is a 0 gas blockchain network.
